# Почему пустой массив?

Tags: c, массивы

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема при выводе массива:

```
char *name_ost[9];
...    
main()
{ 
...
extern void dvijX(...);
 extern void dvijY(...);
 extern void timeDv(...);

...

for(k=0;k<m;k++)
  {
    fscanf(fp3,"%s\n", name_ost[k]);
    outtextxy(510+OstX[k+1], OstY[k+1], name_ost[k]);//здесь вывод есть
  }
  fclose(fp3);

...

dvijX(...);

...

}

void dvijX(...)
{
    ...
        timeDv(...);

        ...
}

void timeDv(...)
{
for(k=1;k<=m;k++)
 {
      ...
       printf(..., name_ost[k-1]);// а тут не выводит
      ...
    }    
}
```

При второй попытке вывести массив, пишет NULL... В чем дело?..

Comment: Как инициализируются `name_ost[k]` (как выделяется память)?

Comment: самая первая строка...

Comment: Вот эта? `char *name_ost[9];` Так там значения `name_ost[k]` инициализируются нулём, а не реальным адресом, куда можно безопасно записать данные. В ответе @adjust это объяснено

Comment: Итак.. Вроде все получилось... Выделил память как сказали @ALEX_LAY_PRO и др.. НО.. При попытке вывести на экран весь массив, при любом k<9 было выведено содержимое последнего элемента так называемого "массива строк"... Насколько я понял здесь fscanf(fp3,"%s\n", name_ost[k]), при каждом чтении массив заполнялся одним значением.. Поэтому при втором выводе пришлось каждый раз читать файл и выводить... Эт неудобно... Как все таки реализовать массив строк, типа name_ost[0] = "word0"...name_ost[k]="wordk"?... http://hashcode.ru/questions/1556/как-записать-в-массив-слова

Comment: Я написал это как дополнение к своему ответу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего в name_ost[k-1] в самом деле нулевой указатель. Почему он там такой, тогда как  k-ый  указывает на нормальную строку, из Ваших фрагментов определить не могу.

**UPD**

А не выделяйте Вы заранее память для слов, на которые указывает name_ost[]. Напишите следующее:

```
for (k = 0; k < m; k++) {
    char buf[1024];
    fscanf(fp3,"%s\n", buf);
    name_ost[k] = strdup(buf);
    outtextxy(510+OstX[k+1], OstY[k+1], name_ost[k]);//здесь вывод есть
}
fclose(fp3);
```

И все будет OK без всякого второго считывания слов, если конечно память нигде не трете.
Совет для отладки. Периодически просто печатайте этот массив.

```
printf ("m = %d\n",m);
for (k = 0; k < m; k++)
    printf ("name_ost[%d] = <%s>\n",k,name_ost[k]);
```

**UPD**

Сразу после fclose(fp3) массив name_ost[] распечатывается нормально ?
Если нет, значит трете память в outtextxy().

Comment: В смысле нулевой указатель?.. Я подправил вопрос...

Comment: m в main() и timeDv() одинаковые ?  Попробуйте печатать k и m по ходу отладки.

Comment: оу... кстати!... хотя m объявлена до main...

Comment: О спасибо) Но почему то вместе слов, пишет один квадрат с точкой внутри!)))

Comment: @Leshij_2005 я буду писать в **UPD** в ответе, а то дурацкий лимит комментариев кончается.

Comment: Изначально массив name_ost[] не выводился сразу после name_ost[k] = strdup(buf)... Но после ознакомления с функцией strdup, стало ясно что надо подключить string.h.. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Корректный спецификатор формата для printf укажите.

Напоминаю, что `printf("%s", string);` выводит 0-terminated строку, а `printf("%c", somechar);` символ, код которого хранится в переменной `somechar`.

К тому же в Си нет проверок на выходы за границы массива и поэтому `k-1` легко может быть, например, отрицательным, что явно смысла не имеет. А что хранится по адресам вне массива - вопрос весьма интересный :-)

Грабли далее - выделение памяти. Дело в том, что указатель должен куда-то ссылаться. Понятное дело, что эта память должна быть выделена заранее. Вариантов два:

Память выделяется динамически.

```
char *x[5]; // массив из 5 указателей на char*
char *y; // если сразу используем y, то как повезет - может указывать на что попало
y = malloc(size); // поэтому выделяем память
...
x[i] = y;
...
// работаем со строчкой x[i] - все ОК.
free(y);
// теперь обращение к x[i] может привести к сбою
```

Память выделяется локально.

```
..
{
  char *x = "temp";
  char y[1000];
  my_array[i] = x;
  my_array[i+1] = y;
}
printf("%s", my_array[i]); //ups! обращаемся к памяти, которая уже освобождена. UB!
```

Поэтому в C++ безопаснее использовать строковые типы как std::string, CString или TString - что предоставляет компилятор и/или среда.

Comment: Я подправил вопрос... k всегда положителен и m=9... В main() спокойно и printf("%s", string); все выводит...

Comment: Ммм ничего не пойму если честно) Первый раз сталкиваюсь с этим... Почему же при первой попытке вывода, все прошло успешно?!.. Да и даже если дальше я в main() использую name_ost то все проходит успешно...

Comment: В первую очередь - нужно выделить память под сами строчки. И присвоить указателям из массива адреса этих блоков. Иначе fscanf начинает писать по произвольным адресам памяти. Ну, или в NULL. И программа в общем случае получается неработоспособной. Удивительно, что у Вас все работает.

Comment: Да, удивительно, но работает!) А выделение памяти эт как раз и есть *name_ost = malloc(9); - получается выделили память для 9 строк, так?...

Comment: нет. Нужно каждый выделять под каждую строчку отдельно. Лучше в цикле. А то, что сделали Вы - выделили 9 байтов =(

Comment: Не удивительно. Глобальные переменные инициализируются нулями. Далее, указатель указывает на адрес. Поскольку это глобальная переменная, указатель указывает на адрес 0. Но если мы пишем слово, мы должны выделить память для указателя, и тогда он указывает на нулевой элемент динамического массива. Поскольку вы память не выделяли, то, кроме нулевого элемента, там ничего нет. Потому и проходит только первый, вернее, нулевой элемент массива.

Comment: Делайте иначе:
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
   name_ost[i]=(int)malloc(9*sizeof(int));
Примерно так=)...

Comment: Удивительно, почему при *name_ost = malloc(9); и m = 9 вообще цикл чтения в name_ost работает ?  Опишите код инициализации подробнее (подправьте код вопроса). 

И еще, посмотрите, м.б. где-то по пути от чтения до timeDv() Вы модифицируете элементы name_ost ? Например случайно в if вместо == написали =.

Comment: Как мы знаем, в параметрах ф-кции malloc передаём размер памяти, который надо выделить. По-этому для выделения памяти под 9 символов пишем malloc(9*sizeof(char)). А насчёт остального кода, которого тут нет, то надо бы его пересмотреть.

Comment: остальной код работает.. зачем выкладывать все, если все места где используется строка перечислены?!..

Comment: Если это ВСЕ места, где есть обращение к элементам name_ost[], то видимо Вы где-то портите память. 

Скорее всего пишете за границы массива, такого же внешнего, как и name_ost[], или читаете в строку (тоже внешнюю) больше, чем ее длина.

Распечатайте адреса первого и последнего элементов всех таких массивов и внимательно посмотрите на них.

Answer (score 1):

> При второй попытке вывести массив, пишет NULL... В чем дело?..

надо выкладывать полный код, особенно, когда он у тебя на таком уровне

**char *name_ost[9];** - глобальный массив

глобальные переменные инициализируются нулём

```
outtextxy(510+OstX[k+1], OstY[k+1], name_ost[k]);//здесь вывод есть
```

это значит, что где-то есть присваивание этим указателям чего-то, иначе fscanf() бы выпала при попытке записи по адресу NULL

неполный код

```
extern void dvijY(...);
```

**extern** зачем ? он там и так предполагается

Answer (score 0):

По-моему в printf() нужно передавать указатель, а не массив. Но могу ошибаться.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/1556/как-записать-в-массив-слова   тут вывод в printf() без указателей...и все правильно выводит...